# Why X-ray imaging base on photon counting is more quick than traditional energy integral detector?

Tags: optics, nuclear-physics, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography, medical-physics

photon counting based on detector can be used to x-ray imaging in industrial pubilc security. In traditional, people often use energy integral scintillation detecor to imaing object through x-ray. The essiential reasons of time saving must be related the difference of the principle  of the detectors.  why X-ray imaging based on photon counting is more quick than traditional energy integral detector?

Comment: This question is really hard to understand.

Comment: in the airport security scanners the photons are weaker than medical X-ray photons .... the security system is only looking thru the cloths which is easier.   ... andmaye only looking to detect metal.....